# Disappearing UILocation alerts in XCode 4.2 with ARC iPhone

Tags: iphone, uialertview

The alerts appear for a split-second or did not show when application launches in project with ARC (without using ARC all it's OK). (I add CoreLocation framework and I import it to project).

My code:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{ 

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"jestem po okienku ");

    if (locationManager.locationServicesEnabled == NO) 
    {
        coordinate.latitude = 0.0;
        coordinate.longitude = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {     
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
        if (!location) {
            coordinate.latitude = 0.0;
            coordinate.longitude = 0.0;
        }
        // Configure the new event with information from the location.
        coordinate = [location coordinate];
    }
    return YES; }
```

Comment: Where in your code are you posting alerts?

Comment: I'm running it in the new project without any other implementation because I want to understand why systems alerts in projects with ARC don't apear when without ARC all is ok.

Comment: Oh, that alert. I didn't understand that from just "the alerts". I should have read the title. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are storing the location manager pointer in a local variable. So ARC is free to release that location manager before returning from this method.

If you wish to keep that location manager alive for longer you need to keep a longer term strong reference to it. Like an ivar or property.

Comment: I am using it as ivar and using strong with it but it still disappearing, what can be the issue?